# Using GParted to remove EFI partition of SSD on USB

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs

I have a problem with GParted not being able to complete an operation.

## Background:

In brief:

- I have a 2Tb M.2 SSD drive that was running Windows 11. Windows suffered a fatal registry failure and could not load. The drive is full of data and content.
- I bought a second 1Tb M.2 and replaced the SSD drive.
- This new SSD drive has a basic windows and a Zorin 16.3 OS duel boot installation set up successfully.
- I have a USB enclosure for the original 2Tb drive.
- Due to the fatal registry error for Windows I was unable to "unmount" the original SSD before removal.

## Status:

In brief:

- The data remains on the 2Tb drive. I need to remove this data or make this drive usable as a USB (ie non booting drive). **I can not format the drive as that will loose the data.**
- The drive in inaccessible to Windows 11 basic install on the "new" duel boot system.
- The drive **IS** accessible on Zorin OS but large file transfers are problematic, there are various secondary issues relating to causing delays and slowness when accessing the drive data via Zorin. The drive is `read-only` on Zorin.

## Issue:

In brief:

- I want to remove the EFI partition on the drive. I use Gparted but this fails to complete this task, instead freezing up, crashing my system overall and generally being unable to complete work either to remove that partition or to remove the `BOOT` / `ESP` flags
- I have also tried doing similar with `diskmgmt.msc` on the windows 11 boot which does see the drive in certain scenarios but I am unable (as windows administrator) to change any aspect of the drive configuration.
- Same applies to `diskpart` as well; it freezes until the M.2 media is physically removed.

### HOW CAN I REMOVE THE EFI PART OF THIS SSD?

As I write this question out, I suspect I may need to put it back into the computer as the primary drive and then boot using the Zorin USB -- HOWEVER -- what can I do after that to remove the boot partition / flags, **BUT NOT DELETE THE DRIVE DATA**?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could it be that the drive has suffered a catastrophic failure, and is now "read-only"? Best bet is to salvage the windows data onto some external media (I missed the part where you did say it's read-only)

Comment: @JaromandaX I have been trying to copy data using Zorin drag / drop from the original SSD to the Zorin drive; but for example copying 4000 files (5.5Gb) it copies 700 files and then Zorin just freezes at a certain point and doesn't complete the operation and can't cease the operation. The only way I found to escape this block is to remove the USB connection. (I am not sure if the issue here is Zorin or the source drive).

Comment: I'd say the source drive has failed catastrophically

Comment: @JaromandaX you're probably not wrong, but I was curious if there was any avenues to save the data -- Please also see updated question with screenshots of the GParted. For some reason there's the key icon by the data partition, I'm not sure how I can make this drive writeable

Comment: Why do you think that removing the EFI partition would solve your problem? In case there is a serious problem with your SSD, you should **not** try to write anything. Copy all data to a diferent drive or to an image file. GNU `ddrescue` is a tool for copying as much as possible from a drive even in case of read errors.

Comment: @Bodo I believe that the windows 11 install on the Zorin duel boot can't read the drive because it is marked as a boot drive. I was looking to remove the EFI partition, and then using windows to copy across files more reliably. My main aim is to extract the data I need and then to clean format the entire 2Tb SSD and eventually put the data back on it.

Comment: Don't forget that the windows partition is NTFS formatted with a modern variant of NTFS and the Linux NTFS drivers aren't *that* great.

Comment: @Martin you should honestly try to recover the data from the NTFS partition using your new Windows installation. It has much better tooling when it comes to repairing NTFS.

Comment: The EFI thing is totally a distraction: the presence of an EFI partition doesn't stop anyone from reading anything else on that disk.

Comment: @MarcusMüller this was my original intention but as stated in the Q, my fresh clean install of Windows 11 sees the USB device but it can't access the device or its content and doesn't seem to recognise it is a data media. I believe(d) this is because of the EFI because I think when Windows accesses the device it sees that it has a windows boot record so doesn't play ball in communicating with it. (sorry lots of guesswork here!)

Comment: @Martin have you checked the status of the drive in Windows "Disk management" - perhaps you can assign a drive letter there

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, disk management (`diskmgmt.msc`) get's stuck and only completes if I unplug the drive. Once disk manager loads ok I can plug the drive back in and then it reads it ok, but I have no abilities to make any changes to the drive.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX same applies to `diskpart` as well, it freezes until the media is physically removed.

Comment: Can you mount read only. The force shutdown and/or hibernation has locked the NTFS partition, it probably needs chkdsk from Windows. https://superuser.com/questions/1231582/hdd-with-windows-boot-locked-because-of-hibernation-flag Or Be sure to make mount point first. `sudo mkdir /media/windows` and `sudo mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/sda1 /media/windows` Double check that sda1 is correct. That often is ESP, and data may be in sda2 or sda3.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I don't have much time before bed, so...</sub>

---

No one commented on watching `dmesg` while doing any and all operations with the drive! (Really, guys!):

As soon as your live or whatever Linux boots up, run this in one window:

```
\dmesg --follow-new --ctime
```

The meaning of the first character (`\`) there is to escape any possible alias.

Now, if you start seeing something like this, your original drive suffered irreversible damage, and only some reputable data recovery company can offer you (maybe) a recovery of your files (the picture is from my real *stories* portfolio):

[image: disk errors]

If you do see some or a lot of "red lines" in your `dmesg` output, go away from your operation immediately and hand it over to specialists.

That being said, you did buy a smaller replacement drive I don't know why. "An error in the matrix, huh :)

Do not try to write anything to the 2TB drive, including the removal of EFI partition, which was also a silly idea. Do not get me wrong, you are inexperienced with this kind of stuff, I get it, but you could make things even worse than they are now. Are we clear? No writes to the 2TB drive, period.

---

I suggest you post the `dmesg` output, either in text (which is always better), or if it freezes again, at least a photo, ok?

I hope this gives you at least information for the start, when I wake up, I might try to edit this answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Smaller secondary SSD was cheaper (money is tight) and intended for only the OS originally. Plan is to extract then format and reuse the 2Tb SSD.

Comment: re `dmesg` - `--follow-new` is not a recognised command. nor is `-W`; version info states: `dmesg from util-linux 2.34`.

Comment: @Martin then you will need to manually hit `dmesg` I suppose repeatedly, I need to go already, cheers

Comment: I have run nautilus (the default file program on this Zorin OS) from the terminal as that comes back with a bunch of error notices `** (org.gnome.Nautilus:435158): WARNING: 20:57:53.784: Unable to get contents of the bookmarks file: Error opening file /root/.gtk-bookmarks: No such file or directory` and
`Nautilus-Share-Message: 20:57:53.866: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Ok, some details you will be wanting to see; I checked the references: the device / partition is sda4; and so running `dmesg | grep sda4` comes back with:

Comment: `[20048.736034] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 58490190, async page read
[20048.736737] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 58490190, async page read
[20057.171658]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5`
etc. etc. there's about 30 lines of this

Comment: FYI After doing more copying work (successfully this time) on the drive, and repeating the `dmesg` it still lists out the same 30 lines of I/O errors

Comment: @Martin I have been on medical leave since today. If there are any amount of IO errors, you won't be able to recover all files, if any at all. Wish you luck. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for your help and best of luck with your medical stuff. I will recover what I can from the drive and explore what can be done to repair it. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can use a clonezilla liveusb to clone your 2 tb ssd on another disk and format the original ssd.

Comment: I have no other physical mechanism to host another drive or anything with enough capacity to hold that data.

Comment: It would be worth buying external media to do this - when you are done, it could be used for making regular data backups.